# Docker containers are going to exited(1) state after sometime

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker containers are deployed through gitlab-ci.yml. In repos we have docker file, Docker-compose.yml, .gitlab-CI.yaml. and some other files. So when run ajob. Container is getting created as expected but it is going to exited state after some time. What Should I do to make it up all the time

```
<Container ID>   <imageID>     "/bin/sh -c 'chown -…"   9 hours ago      Exited (1) About an hour ago
```

Comment: You can use `docker logs ...` or check what happened with your container. Then keep figure it out.

Comment: @Ted Yeah Got it..Thank you

Comment: So what was your problems and how did u solve them ?